# How to develop a webpage with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is: How Can I develop a page using all the fancy components from Bootstrap? Is there any tool with live preview?

Many years ago (web 1.0) I used to use Dreamweaver to create the HTML and basic CSS, but now which tools can I use to basically drag and drop?

Comment: You can use the browser for preview and inspect element for instant feedback.

Comment: Will http://www.layoutit.com/build do it for you?

Comment: Google? http://bit.ly/14DdHWa :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out https://www.easel.io/.  Its a web based ide that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I used these:

[divshot.com](http://divshot.com)
[Jetstrap.io](http://jetstrap.io)